# handlebars each in pug error

Tags: handlebars.js, pug

I m looping handlebars {{#each}} in pug template.

Pug displays the error message "unexpected token "indent".

Maybe someone else had a similar error?

```
 script( id="search-result-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template")
    .col-xs-12.search-result__item(id="{{index}}")
        .search-result__item__title {{title}}
        .search-result__item__text {{text}}
        .search-result__item__links
          {{#each links as link}}
              a(href="{{link.url}}").search-result__item__links__item {{link.name}}
          {{/each}}
```

[image: image error]

Use gulp width pug

[link to CodePen](https://codepen.io/zif001/pen/dVqYgx)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution
In this block add |

```
.search-result__item__links
          | {{#each links as link}}
          | a(href="{{link.url}}").search-result__item__links__item {{link.name}}
          | {{/each}}
```